# Как сделать независимые столбцы из одной таблицы и в последующем к ним обращаться?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, datagrip, oracle11g

Есть следующие таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE SportTypes( 
  SportTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  SportTypeName VARCHAR(30));

CREATE TABLE Sportsmans(  
  SportsmanID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
  FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  MiddleName VARCHAR(50),  
  LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
  SportTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT fk_sporttype FOREIGN KEY (SportTypeID) REFERENCES SportTypes(SportTypeID));

CREATE TABLE Competitions(   
  CompetitionID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   
  CompetitionName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   
  Season VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   
  SportTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL,   
  CONSTRAINT fk_sporttype2 FOREIGN KEY (SportTypeID) REFERENCES SportTypes(SportTypeID));

CREATE TABLE Results(   
  SportsmanID INTEGER NOT NULL,   
  CompetitionID INTEGER NOT NULL,   
  Result INTEGER NOT NULL,   
  CONSTRAINT fk_sportsman FOREIGN KEY (SportsmanID) REFERENCES Sportsmans(SportsmanID), 
  CONSTRAINT fk_competition FOREIGN KEY (CompetitionID) REFERENCES Competitions(CompetitionID), 
  CONSTRAINT pk_results PRIMARY KEY (SportsmanID, CompetitionID));
```

Необходимо вывести всех спортсменов (все атрибуты спортсмена) + лучший спортсмен в его виде спорта + худший спортсмен в его виде спорта (лучший / худший считается на основе «среднего места» в данном виде спорта).

Проблема возникает у меня на этапе, когда нужно по результату (лучшему и худшему) получить различных спортсменов, поскольку я не могу сообразить, как сделать независимые столбцы из одной таблицы и как в последующем к ним обращаться.

Сам запрос пока только такой:

```
select "ID", "sp1First", "sp1Last", "sp1Middle", "sID", 
       min(avgRes) over (partition by SportTypeName) as BestRes
  from (select sp1.SportsmanID as "ID", sp1.FirstName as "sp1First", sp1.LastName as "sp1Last", sp1.MiddleName as "sp1Middle", 
               sp1.SportTypeID as "sID", SportTypeName, 
               avg(Result) over (partition by sp1.SportsmanID, Competitions.SportTypeID) as avgRes
          from Sportsmans sp1 inner join Results on sp1.SportsmanID = Results.SportsmanID
               inner join Competitions on Results.CompetitionID = Competitions.CompetitionID
               inner join SportTypes on SportTypes.SportTypeID = Competitions.SportTypeID
               inner join Sportsmans sp2 on sp2.SportsmanID = Results.SportsmanID);
```

Comment: Как именно нужно выводить лучших и худших? Отдельной строкой, признаком в отдельном столбце, еще как-то? И запрос тоже показывайте.

Comment: Покажите, что у вас уже получилось. Вы повысите качество вопроса, если создадите схему на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), например.

Comment: Запрос, которым вы уже можете выбрать хотя бы одного (лучшего или худшего) или просто считающий этот самый рейтинг сильно облегчит задачу отвечающему, ему не надо будет писать все с нуля ...

Comment: @Dmitry насколько я понимаю, нужно признаком в отдельном столбце, запрос добавил

Comment: А что имеется ввиду под "_+ лучший спортсмен_", какая информация о таком спортсмене вам интересна ? Можно использовать например `first_value(sp1First)  over (partition by SportTypeName order by avgRes)` что бы получить имя спортсмена с наименьшим средним баллом. И аналогичный last_value что бы получить с максимальным

Answer (score 0):

Почти правильно, осталось только сравнить максимум и минимум в каждом виде спорта с результатом каждого спортсмена:

```
select "ID", "sp1First", "sp1Last", "sp1Middle", "sID", 
       case when min(avgRes) over (partition by SportTypeName) = avgRes then 'Best'
            when max(avgRes) over (partition by SportTypeName) = avgRes then 'Worse' 
            else null end as BestWorseRes
  from (select sp1.SportsmanID as "ID", sp1.FirstName as "sp1First", 
               sp1.LastName as "sp1Last", sp1.MiddleName as "sp1Middle", 
               sp1.SportTypeID as "sID", SportTypeName, 
               avg(Result) over (partition by sp1.SportsmanID, Competitions.SportTypeID) as avgRes
          from Sportsmans sp1 inner join Results on sp1.SportsmanID = Results.SportsmanID
               inner join Competitions on Results.CompetitionID = Competitions.CompetitionID
               inner join SportTypes on SportTypes.SportTypeID = Competitions.SportTypeID
               inner join Sportsmans sp2 on sp2.SportsmanID = Results.SportsmanID);
```

И еще я это не понял:

> лучший / худший считается на основе «среднего места» в данном виде спорта

Имеется в виду среднее место данного спортсмена в каждом виде? Если да, то все ок.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю самое простое решение это предвычислить средние результаты

```
;with cte as (
         select r.SportsmanID
               ,c.SportTypeID
               ,avg(r.Result)            as avgRes
                Results as r
                inner join Competitions  as c
                on r.CompetitionID = c.CompetitionID
         group by
                c.SportTypeID
               ,r.SportsmanID
     )
select "ID"
      ,"sp1First"
      ,"sp1Last"
      ,"sp1Middle"
      ,"sID"
      ,Sportsman_min_res
      ,min_avg_res
      ,Sportsman_max_res
      ,max_avg_res
from   (
           select sp1.SportsmanID      as "ID"
                 ,sp1.FirstName        as "sp1First"
                 ,sp1.LastName         as "sp1Last"
                 ,sp1.MiddleName       as "sp1Middle"
                 ,sp1.SportTypeID      as "sID"
                 ,SportTypeName
                 ,min_res.SportsmanID  as Sportsman_min_res
                 ,min_res.avgRes       as min_avg_res
                 ,max_res.SportsmanID  as Sportsman_max_res
                 ,max_res.avgRes       as max_avg_res
           from   Sportsmans           as sp1
                  inner join Results
                       on  sp1.SportsmanID = Results.SportsmanID
                  inner join Competitions
                       on  Results.CompetitionID = Competitions.CompetitionID
                  inner join SportTypes
                       on  SportTypes.SportTypeID = Competitions.SportTypeID
                  outer apply (
                             select top 1 cte.SportsmanID
                                   ,cte.avgRes
                             from   cte
                             where  cte.SportTypeID = sp1.SportTypeID
                             order by
                                    avgRes desc
                            )          as min_res
                     outer apply (
                            select top 1 cte.SportsmanID
                                      ,cte.avgRes
                            from   cte
                            where  cte.SportTypeID = sp1.SportTypeID
                            order by
                                      avgRes asc
                            )                  as max_res
);
```

Извините меня, если код не работает, я не знаю plsql, я специализируюсь на tsql, по идее должно работать.